# Javascript: could not get the value inside an array using for in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the form with user filled values inside the form to admin. I have displayed all type of values to the respective type of input/select/textarea tags (type: text,email, tel,number... etc) except input type=checkbox.

I am getting problem while fetching the values from array that contain values of group of checkboxes. My code is

```
                    var value = data[i][key];
                var result = $.isArray(value);
                if (result == true) {
                    var string = key;
                    var splitstring = string.split("#");
                    for (var value1 in value) {
                        console.log(value1);
                        $("input[type='checkbox'][groupid='" + splitstring[0] + "'][value='" + value1 + "']").attr('checked', true);  //cb
                    }
                }
```

my array(named value) contain values like
    [cricket, football, tennis]

would like to make the checkbox property checked that match the condition. but when i console the values fetched one by one it shows me output as
    0
    1
    2

i am not getting what is it???

my html code

```
                <table class="form-group">
                <tbody id="tedit">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input id="dddddddd#1428735544884535#check_box1" class="form-control" name="14287355448849394#dddddddd[]" groupid="14287355448849394" grid-name="dddddddd" value="Check Box1" type="checkbox" /><label class="jedit"><span class="mouseover">Check Box1</span></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input id="dddddddd#14287355448843282#check_box2" class="form-control" groupid="14287355448849394" grid-name="dddddddd" name="14287355448849394#dddddddd[]" value="Check Box2" type="checkbox" /> <label class="jedit"> <span class="mouseover">Check Box2</span></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input id="dddddddd#14287355448853367#check_box3" class="form-control" groupid="14287355448849394" grid-name="dddddddd" name="14287355448849394#dddddddd[]" value="Check Box3" type="checkbox" /> <label class="jedit"> <span class="mouseover">Check Box3</span></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

my javascript code is

```
$.post('<?php echo BASE_URL . 'php/processing/formDashboard/formEntryShowOneByOne.php' ?>', {id: $('#formMetaDataId').val()}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            for (var key in data[i]) {
                $("input[type='text'][name='" + key + "']").val(data[i][key]); //input tags
                $("input[type='text'][name='" + key + "']").prop('disabled', 'true'); //input tags

//........likewise for other type of elements.......///

//.....................for checkbox........................//
                var value = data[i][key];
                var result = $.isArray(value);
                if (result == true) {
                    var string = key;
                    var splitstring = string.split("#");
                    for (var value1 in value) {
                        console.log(value1);
                        $("input[type='checkbox'][groupid='" + splitstring[0] + "'][value='" + value1 + "']").attr('checked', true);  //cb
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your form html code and full loop code.

Comment: well the html is too big so i have posted only the checkbox part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple. The 'cricket' string is retrievable like this:

```
value[value1]
```

value1 is just the iterator, in your example 0,1,2

This is your working code:

```
var value = data[i][key];
var result = $.isArray(value);
if (result == true) {
    var string = key;
    var splitstring = string.split("#");
    for (var value1 in value) {
        console.log(value[value1]);
        $("input[type='checkbox'][groupid='" + splitstring[0] + "'][value='" + value[value1] + "']").attr('checked', true);  //cb
    }
}
```

Comment: oh! i that is the way. i supposed to thing the loop as of PHP foreach loop. Thanks i accept this ans

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forEach` function

```
value.forEach(function(val)
{
  console.log(val);
  //do your thing here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the `for ... in` loop works for arrays:

```js
var a = ['a','b','c'];
for (var i in a) {
  alert(i); // alerts 0,1,2
  alert(a[i]); // alerts a,b,c
}
```

Thus, you just need to index your array with the loop variable:

```
var value = data[i][key];
var result = $.isArray(value);
if (result == true) {
    var string = key;
    var splitstring = string.split("#");
    for (var valueIndex in value) {
        console.log(value[valueIndex]);
        $("input[type='checkbox'][groupid='" + splitstring[0] + "'][value='" + value[valueIndex] + "']").attr('checked', true);  //cb
    }
}
```